# Расположить элемент справа на десктопе и слева на мобильном Bootstrap4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

В проекте используется `bootstrap4`. Имеется навигация `navbar` в которой есть логотип и пункты меню. По умолчанию в bootstrap логотип `navbar-brand` всегда слева.

За основу взяла `navbar-light` [отсюда](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/examples/navbars/).

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light rounded navbar-toggleable-md">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#containerNavbar" aria-controls="containerNavbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="containerNavbar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown04" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown04">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </nav>
```

Как расположить `navbar-brand` справа для десктопа и слева для мобильных?

**UPD**

Суть вопроса: как расположить `navbar-brand` (логотип) по правому краю для десктопа (для ширины `md` и больше), и по левому для мобильных?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Управлять расположением бренда(логотипа) можно с помощью классов `flex-first`, `flex-last`, др . Для отображения на необходимых разрешениях можно использовать все те же приставки `-lg`, `-md`, `-sm`, `-xs`.

[Ресурс](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/)

Пример:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  
<nav class="navbar navbar-light rounded navbar-toggleable-md justify-content-between">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#containerNavbar" aria-controls="containerNavbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand flex-xs-first flex-md-last" href="#">Navbar</a>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="containerNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown04" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown04">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: суть вопроса: как расположить `navbar-brand` по правому краю для десктопа (для ширины `md` и больше), и по левому для мобильных

Comment: @MarinaVoronova, исправила ответ

Comment: ваш код работает так как нужно, но почему-то у меня не работает. нужно как-то отдельно включать флексы?

Comment: @MarinaVoronova, проверьте версию, тут выше html подключены используемые мной файлы

Comment: версия та же - Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.6. поискала класс `flex-xs-first` по вашей ссылке, не находит... очень странно

Comment: спасибо за помощь! перезагрузка компа помогла)

Comment: @MarinaVoronova, все так просто оказалось)