# Как в Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.6 подключить классы с flex?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, flexbox

В проекте используется Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.6. Для выравнивания элементов задаю классы `flex`, например `justify-content-xs-start`. Не работает.

Пыталась подключить `flex` в файле `_variables.scss`, но там вообще не оказалось строки `$enable-flex: true !default;`. Добавила ее, но это не помогло.

Необходимые классы находятся в файле `_flex.scss`. Как их включить?

Comment: Какой номер альфа версии вы используете? Кажется, вы используете новую альфу (4 или 6), а документацию смотрите по старой.

Comment: Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.6

Comment: В этой версии нет таких классов. Можете уточнить, откуда вы взяли информацию о них? Актуальная документация здесь: http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/

Comment: смотрю везде, но ничего не могу найти для решения вопроса

Comment: есть такие классы  `.justify-content#{$infix}-start   { justify-content: flex-start !important; }` в файле `_flex.scss`

Comment: началось все с этого вопроса http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/648565/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-bootstrap4/648576

Comment: прошу прощения, опечаталась. но вопрос в силе

Comment: @VenZell, https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/#order , а не grid и все  работает если подключать css\js со стартовой стр. а вот с scss видимо неправильно подключен bootstrap, либо не со всеми необходимыми компонентами

Comment: @MarinaVoronova, может быть не подключили флекс. `// Utility classes
@import "utilities";` или `// Utility classes
@import "utilities/flex";`

Comment: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/v4-dev/scss

Comment: утилиты подключены. подключаю бутстрап импортом в мой файл со стилями. а в самом бутстрапе так https://jsfiddle.net/xqk06L35/. в `custom` (это variables) только цвета и отступы меняю

Comment: проверила, все утилиты кроме `flex` работают без проблем

Comment: после перезагрузки компа все работает)

Answer (score 0):

В Bootstrap 4 flexbox grid включен по-умолчанию. Добавьте на страницу `div` с классами `.row`, `.col` и увидете, что все работает на флексбоксах

Comment: вижу, но классы c flex почему-то не работают